# Find a String from a varying number block to the end

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have nearly 8000 lines of the following text:

```
DIL 2 M 006 SC  SCHÜTZ  083 1 Stck  
25215-1 BIN-SORT 2152310251724-1 BIN-SORT getestet 048 133 Stck  
RBBE60-T3dsg 21S003  SEALING 6X8.9X2.4 MM 082 3 Stck
```

I am only interested in the 3 digit block at the end and the number behind.

So this should be the output:

```
083 1 
048 133   
082 3
```

It could be, that the same number e.g. 048 appears at the beginning of the line. this shouldn't be a hit.

Unfortunatelly i have no idea how to extract this strings with the help of notpad++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression,

```
.*(\d{3}\s+\d+).*
```

with a replacement of `$1` is likely to work here.

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/KLs82f/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^.*?(\d+ \d+) \S*$
Replace: $1
```

The logic here is to use `.*` to consume everything up until the last two consecutive digits in the line.  Then, we replace with only the captured two digits.

### Demo